# How to Vue.use() a javascript plugin in a TypeScript project that does have typings

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, semantic-ui

I am trying to use `Semantic-UI-Vue` in my vue project. However, I am getting the following error when I try and do `Vue.use(SuiVue)`:

> Argument of type 'typeof import("semantic-ui-vue")' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PluginObject<{}> | PluginFunction<{}>'.\n Type 'typeof import("semantic-ui-vue")' is not assignable to type 'PluginFunction<{}>'.\n Type 'typeof import("semantic-ui-vue")' provides no match for the signature '(Vue: VueConstructor, options?: {} | undefined): void'."

I have created a `.d.ts` file that lets me import SuiVue:

```
declare module 'semantic-ui-vue'{}
```

And I import it in my `app.ts` as:

```
import * as SuiVue from 'semantic-ui-vue';
```

What do I need to do to get this plugin to be usable in a typescript project without disabling global TypeScript settings like `noImplicitAny`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `declare module 'semantic-ui-vue'{}` with `declare module 'semantic-ui-vue';`

---

`declare module 'semantic-ui-vue'{}` means the module have the type of an empty object `{}`.

`declare module 'semantic-ui-vue';` means the module have the type any

see **Shorthand ambient modules** in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

---

As the OP has figured out, you need to change the import statement to `import SuiVue from 'semantic-ui-vue';` for it to work

Comment: Hm, this gets rid of the error. But no components register.

Comment: Had to also change the import to `import SuiVue from 'semantic-ui-vue'`. If you add that into your answer I'll mark it.